# Self join in Django

Tags: django-orm

To perform a query with self-join on the following table:

```
> select * from test_users
id  email
--- -----------
1   "a@abc.com"
2   "a@abc.com"
3   "b@abc.com"
```

I can use SQL:

```
> select u1.id u1id, u2.id u2id from test_users u1 inner join test_users u2 on u1.email=u2.email and u1.id !=u2.id
u1id   u2id
-----  ------
1      2
2      1
```

Question:

1. How can I write this in Django ORM?
2. If I want to remove the duplicate so that I get only 1 row in above example, how can I achieve that in Django?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can retrieve the `User`s for which there is another item with a primary key that is greater than (or less than) the primary key of the user with an [**`Exists`** subquery [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#exists-subqueries):

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef

Users.objects.filter(
    Exists(
        User.objects.filter(
            pk__gt=OuterRef('pk'),
            email=OuterRef('email')
        )
    )
)
```

If you thus call `.delete()` on these, you will remove all `User`s for wich another `Users` object exists with a greater primary key.

Prior to [django-3.0](/questions/tagged/django-3.0), one should move the `Exists` subquery to an `.annotate(…)` clause, and then filter on this:

```
from django.db.models import Exists, OuterRef

Users.objects.annotate(
    has_other=Exists(
        User.objects.filter(
            pk__gt=OuterRef('pk'),
            email=OuterRef('email')
        )
    )
).filter(has_other=True)
```

Comment: I got this error:


    >>> qs = User.objects.filter(Exists(pk__gt=OuterRef('pk'),email=OuterRef('email')))
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/opt/rh/rh-python36/root/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/expressions.py", line 1065, in __init__
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'queryset'
>>>

Comment: @techie11: sorry I made a mistake. That should be fixed now.

Comment: I got "TypeError: 'Exists' object is not iterable" error. Please see in my post.

Comment: @techie11: what Django version do you use?

Comment: @techie11: prior to Django-3.0, you should use annotate first.

Comment: I'm using django-2.0.7

Comment: @techie11: then the code fragment at the bottom of the answer should do the trick.

Comment: The query works now. but I can access one ID (pk) onlu. how can I access the other ID related by email?